# Trying to use a list until his end on a action in Python

Tags: python, list, python-turtle

I'm coding in python and I don't know much about python yet.

I'm trying to make the turtle.color() read each element in a list for not repeating turtle color so many times.

First I tried this but it was too big, and I think can be writen in a simpler way

```
import turtle from turtle import * 

Turtle = turtle.Turtle() 
turtle.color(red) 
turtle.color('orange')
turtle.color('yellow')
turtle.color('green') 
turtle.color('cyan')
turtle.color('blue')
turtle.color('purple')
```

I wrote this list with the color names, but I don't know how to start.

```
list = ["red", 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'purple']
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `for`-loop, also do not name list `list` unless you desire to shadow `list` built-in, simple example

```
import turtle
colors = ["red", 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'purple']
for color in colors:
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.forward(15) # do something so we can see effect of color setting
```

Comment: Thank you, I could did the code before I see the the answer, but I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["red", 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'purple']

for color in list:
    turtle.color(color)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?